SSL-enabled subdomain not activating service in FreeTAKServer dashboard
The issue is I have hosted both the UI and Server using one instance so the IP is same
now I have created sub domain and mapped it with the UI and added SSL
and as the server is on http so it displays that service is running but not activated in the dashboard.
while removing subdomain and running it on IP using http it is working properly
I have installed latest version of FreeTAKServer which is 2.1.3 and FreeTAKServer-UI which is 2.1.1.2.
Python version is 3.11.7 and the OS is Ubuntu, 22.04 LTS, amd64 jammy image
FreeTAKServer-UI Dashboard
The is config.py in FreeTAKServer-UI
Config.py image-1
Config.py image-2
The given link is  GitHub repo the project
https://github.com/FreeTAKTeam/FreeTakServer
Documentation:
https://freetakteam.github.io/FreeTAKServer-User-Docs/
I have created sub domains for the server but as there are 6 ports so it didn't worked
The given image is reference of the ports which are running on http using IP when I have not linked sub domain with the UI. but when I created sub domain for UI then all the ports are stopped woking:
Ports in FreeTAKServer
